# Generic function that receives different STL containers [C++]

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, generics, stl

I have a question regarding a C++ code. My task is to create a generic function that receives different STL containers (vector, list, set) and counts the odd numbers in them.

My first try is:

```
template <typename T>
void countOdd(T x)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = x.begin(); i < x.size(); i++)
        if (x % 2 == 1)
            count++;
    cout << count;
}
```

However i get lots of errors and I believe it is not the right way.

Comment: Please share the exact compiler errors. And what is `T`? Are you missing `template<typename T>` from the code snippet?

Comment: There is no container in the standard library for which `x.begin()` would return an `int`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: x.begin() returns a iterator not an int.  x is the container, not the element inside of the container, you can't perform x%2 on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of issues. This loop:

```
for (int i = x.begin(); i < x.size(); i++)
```

is incorrect. `begin()` returns an iterator, not an index.

Also this condition:

```
if (x % 2 == 1)
```

is incorrect, since `x` is the range being passed in, not the individual elements.

The simplest way to do this is:

```
template<typename T>
void countOdd(T const & range)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto const &element : range)
        if (element % 2 != 0)
            count++;
    cout << count;
}
```

From c++20, you can reduce the boilerplate for the template and write:

```
void countOdd(auto const & range)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto const &element : range)
        if (element % 2 != 0)
            count++;
    cout << count;
}
```

And finally, you should use an appropriate algorithm, so you can do:

```
void countOdd(auto const & range)
{
  cout << std::count_if(std::begin(range), std::end(range),
                        [](auto element) { return element % 2 != 0; });
}
```

Comment: A much more generic and efficient solution.  Though `element % 2 == 1` is wrong too of course. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc813c36c65feb4

Comment: @Deduplicator Aah, good point, didn't consider negatives. Converted to `!= 0` instead. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You need `template`.

then more common attribute are begin/end instead of begin/size (and begin return iterator, not `int`)

so you might do

```
template <typename Container>
std::size_t countOdd(const Container& cont)
{
    return std::count_if(std::begin(cont), std::end(cont),
                         [](auto e){ return e % 2 != 0; });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am still learning and it has been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The function you are supposed to implement is a use-case for [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). The possible implementation from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

> ```
> template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
> typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
>     count_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
> {
>     typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type ret = 0;
>     for (; first != last; ++first) {
>         if (p(*first)) {
>             ret++;
>         }
>     }
>     return ret;
> }
> ```

Standard algorithms take iterators as parameter and container provide methods to get iterators to the first element `begin()` and one past the last element `end()`.

The predicate is a callable that takes an element as parameter and returns a `bool` to indicate whether the element should be counted or not.

We can wrap that into a function that takes the container as parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container>
auto count_odds(const Container& c) {
    auto is_odd = [](auto element)->bool { return element % 2;};
    return std::count_if(c.begin(),c.end(),is_odd);
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
    std::cout << count_odds(v);
}
```